# Reassigning the values of a 2D array

Tags: java

EDIT: Thank you to everyone who helped me understand what i have to do and what the problem was.

SudokuStuff interface

```
public interface SudokuStuff
{
  int[][] sudokuGrid = new int[][] {{2,4,0,6,8,0,3,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0}, 
            {6,5,0,0,1,0,0,8,7},
            {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,9,8},
            {9,3,2,5,0,8,7,1,4},
            {7,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
            {4,9,0,0,7,0,0,2,5},
            {0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,1,0,4,5,0,7,3}}; 
  void addNumber(int x, int y, int value);
  void removeNumber(int x, int y);
  void resetGrid();
  void drawGrid();
}
```

Sudoku class

```
public class Sudoku implements SudokuStuff{

    public void drawGrid(){
        System.out.println("   -----   -----   ----- ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if(i==3||i==6){
                System.out.println("   -----   -----   ----- ");
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                if(j==0||j==3||j==6){ 
                    System.out.print(" |");
                }
                if(sudokuGrid[i][j] != 0){
                    System.out.print(" "+sudokuGrid[i][j]);
                } else{
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
                if(j==8){ 
                    System.out.print(" |");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("   -----   -----   -----  ");
    }

    public void addNumber(int x, int y, int value){
        if(x>9||x<1||y>9||y<1||value>9||value<0){
            System.out.println("Bad Input");
        }else{
            sudokuGrid[x-1][y-1] = value;
        }
        drawGrid();
    }

    public void removeNumber(int x, int y){
        if(x>9||x<1||y>9||y<1){
            System.out.println("Bad Input");
        }else{
            sudokuGrid[x-1][y-1] = 0;
        }
        drawGrid();
    }
    public void resetGrid(){
        sudokuGrid = {{2,4,0,6,8,0,3,0,0}, 
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0}, 
            {6,5,0,0,1,0,0,8,7},
            {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,9,8},
            {9,3,2,5,0,8,7,1,4},
            {7,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
            {4,9,0,0,7,0,0,2,5},
            {0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,1,0,4,5,0,7,3}};
        drawGrid();
    }
}
```

So to get to my question, in SudokuStuff i have a 2D with preset values, in Sudoku i have a resetGrid method that doesn't work. as you can see i want it to reset the grid to its original form. Any suggestions on doing that? What i have now gives me an illegal start of expression error.

And a side note if you know that answer, is there any way to run the methods in Sudoku from SudokuStuff in the interactions pane. This is a practice question for my midterm and im still confused with the interface thing.

Any help will  be greatly appreciated, if i don't answer right away its probably because i passed out because its very late at night here. Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of `SodokuStuff`? Do you plan on having multiple implementations of some sort of Sodoku?

Comment: Do you know that fields declared in interface are static and final? In other words they are constants.

Comment: @Pshemo Then how come i can change them with my add/removeNumber methods, im not doubting you i just dont know.

Comment: @Kevin Like I pointed in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21807976/1393766) move this field from interface to your class.

Comment: @Pshemo sorry didnt realize you were the same person that posted that answer, i posted a reply to it, thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Array initializers (IE, surrounded by {}) do not work outside of declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields declared in interface are `static` and **`final`** (not to mention `public`), in other words they are constants which mean you can't reassign them.

If you want to be able to do something like

```
public void resetGrid(){
    sudokuGrid = new int[][]{
        {2,4,0,6,8,0,3,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0}, 
        {6,5,0,0,1,0,0,8,7},
        {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,9,8},
        {9,3,2,5,0,8,7,1,4},
        {7,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
        {4,9,0,0,7,0,0,2,5},
        {0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,4,5,0,7,3}
    };
    drawGrid();
}
```

you should make `int[][] sudokuGrid` field in your class.

Edit:

If this array has to be declared in interface then you can try reassigning its rows (they are not final). Here is example of how you can do it:

```
public void resetGrid(){
    int[][] tmp = {
        {2,4,0,6,8,0,3,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0}, 
        {6,5,0,0,1,0,0,8,7},
        {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,9,8},
        {9,3,2,5,0,8,7,1,4},
        {7,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
        {4,9,0,0,7,0,0,2,5},
        {0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,4,5,0,7,3}
    };
    for (int i=0; i<sudokuGrid.length; i++)
        sudokuGrid[i]=tmp[i];
    drawGrid();
}
```

Comment: My instructor wants me to keep the interface class unchanged, so im learing how to use 2D arrays and interfaces at the same time.

Comment: Thats a perfect way to get around it it being final without doing this http://puu.sh/6Y1Bs/ab6413d09e.txt, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your reset function doesn't work is that you're declaring a new variable with the same name in the resetGrid function, rather than assigning the values you want to the class level variable.  Take away the type on sudokuGrid and it ought to work.

Comment: Sory for the confustion i think i confussed Smitty aswell, the reason i was redeclaring it there was because i was testing something, when i do just sudokuGrid = {...} it gives me illegal start of exprestion.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Others explained why that was.  You probably wouldn't want to do it that way anyway, because it requires you to have the right values in 2 places in your code.  Generally that's bad-  if you change one you'll forget to change the other.  I'll give you a hint-  the right solution involves a "deep copy" of the array- copying not just the reference location, but all of the individual values so you have a current and initial state of the game grid.

Comment: ill put more thought into it, thanks. But im going to call it a night. Ill check back tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `new int[][]` as such:

```
sudokuGrid = new int[][] {...};
```

I don't think(?) it even compiles otherwise.  You can only use the `= {...}` when declaring a variable, not reassigning one.

Final:

```
public void resetGrid(){
    sudokuGrid = new int[][] {{2,4,0,6,8,0,3,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0}, 
        {6,5,0,0,1,0,0,8,7},
        {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,9,8},
        {9,3,2,5,0,8,7,1,4},
        {7,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
        {4,9,0,0,7,0,0,2,5},
        {0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,4,5,0,7,3}};
}
```

**Edit after comments**:

Ok edit totally off the top of my head without really think about it.  Have a static final array of "defaults" and use it to reset the array you modify:

```
static final int[][] defaultGrid = new int[][] {{2,4,0,6,8,0,3,0,0}, 
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0}, 
        {6,5,0,0,1,0,0,8,7},
        {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,9,8},
        {9,3,2,5,0,8,7,1,4},
        {7,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
        {4,9,0,0,7,0,0,2,5},
        {0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,4,5,0,7,3}};

...

// This will reset the grid to whatever is in defaultGrid
// assuming they have the same lengths
for (int i = 0; i = sudokuGrid.length; i++) {
   for (int y = 0; y = sudokuGrid[y].length; y++) {
      sudokuGrid[i][y] = defaultGrid[i][y];
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i hat the int[][] there when i was testing stuff, when i try to use

    sudokuGrid = {{2,4,0,6,8,0,3,0,0}, 
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0}, 
                {6,5,0,0,1,0,0,8,7},
                {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,9,8},
            {9,3 ,2,5,0,8,7,1,4},
            {7,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
            {4,9,0,0,7,0,0,2,5},
            {0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,1,0,4,5,0,7,3}};

it says illegal start of expression.

Comment: Sorry, i messed up when imputing what you suggested, however you are right about i not reassigning a final, but how come removeNumber and addNumber work? Guess ill have to google more stuff to figure out how to reset the values.

Comment: Sorry to use a link instead of just posting it but i dont know how to formoat code in comments. i guess i can just do this but it seems kind of overkill. http://puu.sh/6Y1Bs/ab6413d09e.txt

Comment: Because they are only setting values inside the array, not creating a new array.  When you call resetGrid(), you are creating and assigning a new array[][] reference to variable sudokuGrid.  Does that make sense?  I can elaborate if need be.

Comment: Yes, technically that will work as you are just assigning new values to the items of the array.  I'm gonna edit my post with a suggestion.

Comment: Ok, so long story short, there is no way to reset the values using the format in my original post, i have to do it individually like the link i just sent? And thanks for all your help tonight but i think im going to call it a night, ill check back tomorrow as soon as i can.

Comment: Just saww the edit now, you and Pshemo seem to come to the same conclusion, thank you both for the help. Btw, what does new int[][] do, because it compiles and works just dine without it.

Comment: Using the `sud = new int[][] {...}` creates a new array.  Just using the bracket notation of `{...}` is only valid when declaring an array, not reassigning it which is what you are trying to do.  In other words, when you create a new array type variable, the compiler allows you to use the `{...}` as a shortcut.  But after that you have to use the `new...`

Comment: Thank you very much for all your patients, but unfortunately im dead tired and im going to begone for the night. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're going to run into is variables declared in an interface are essentially final. You can do a few different things, but the easiest you can do is to create a variable within sudoku that you populate by cloning sudokuGrid into it at runtime, and on reset, simply reset the value of it by recloning sudokuGrid again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ill get back to you soon hopefully once i Google how to do that. Still kinda new to programming.